# Android Audio Streaming Service

Tags: android, audio, service, audio-streaming

I have run into a problem lately regarding audio streaming service. I have created a service which successfully streams audio and playlists, but the issue is that the app crashes sometimes when the network is unavailable or if I switch from wifi to data network, it throws an IllegalStateException. I have avoided the crash using a try catch block, but I am not actually satisfied with it. It would be great if someone would guide me to how to handle network states when streaming audio using a bound service and how to stop/pause playback if network is un-available and resume playback if the network is available again.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Give the code for setting up and tearing down the stream.